# I was down graded by -5?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-accounts

In my math.stackexchange account, it says user was removed and deducted -5 reputations. What does this mean? I don't know whether it's the right place to ask this question.

Please help!

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/reputation-decrease-citing-user-was-removed  and the questions linked there.

Comment: thanks for the support